# how can i make a CRC in typescript or javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, crc

now, i have a need when user send Hexadecimal array like [01 06 00 01 00 10]
the Divisor is '11000000000000101'

who knows how to do it or give me a example in js or ts

Comment: simply use some npm package i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/crc

Answer (score 1):

More information is needed to answer your question. A CRC is defined not just by the polynomial (for which you have provided a common 16-bit CRC polynomial, `0x8005` or x<sup>16</sup>+x<sup>15</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>+1) but also the order in which the bits from the bytes are fed to the CRC, the initial value of the CRC register, and the order of the bits from the CRC to make the result. You may also need to know the order of the two bytes of the 16-bit CRC as they are placed in the message (little or big endian).

From [a list of known CRCs](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/16.htm), I see seven different 16-bit CRC definitions that use that polynomial, with various choices of bit orderings, initial values and final CRCs.

You would need to find and provide that information, or at least provide several examples of messages and their CRCs in order to try to derive its definition.

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example of a function in JavaScript that takes in a hexadecimal array and a divisor and returns the remainder when the hexadecimal number represented by the array is divided by the divisor:

```js
function divideHexArray(hexArray, divisor) {
  let hexNumber = "";
  
  // convert hexadecimal array to hexadecimal string
  for (let i = 0; i < hexArray.length; i++) {
    hexNumber += hexArray[i].toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
  }
  
  // convert hexadecimal string to decimal number
  let decimalNumber = parseInt(hexNumber, 16);
  
  // divide decimal number by divisor and return the remainder
  return decimalNumber % divisor;
}
```

Comment: Um, no. The kind of division required for CRC calculations is the division of _polynomials_ over GF(2). Not integer division.